# Save Form loses added fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form, they can add any number of appendages. In addition I have a JavaScript function:

```
function CreateField()
{
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<textarea name="attachement_1"></textarea>';
    var span = document.getElementById('media_template_attachment');
    span.parentNode.insertBefore(div, span);

    alert(span.parentNode.innerHTML);
}
```

And I've inspired me on this post: [Dynamically generated form field loses value when new field is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826816/dynamically-generated-form-field-loses-value-when-new-field-is-added)

In my HTML file, I have a form:

```
<form name="modify_post_form" action="?save=modify_post" method="post">

<a href="javascript:CreateField();">Add</a>

<td><span id="media_template_attachment" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</td>
```

When I add an item (javascript: add) I get it in the browser window.
The alert gives the following content:

[image: Result of my CreateFunction]

When I click on "Save", and with PHP examine the POST data, I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [area_id] => 6
    [subject] => Mail
    [description] => test test
    [id] => 486
)
```

That is, the added item, although it will probably appear in the browser window, and is available as HTML code, it will not be sent with POST data. Why? I do not understand. Has anyone might have an idea?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me - sends the dynamically added fields. Use profiler or check your browser's network tab the request and data sent.. If you observe the problem give us your browser name, version etc. and give us not working jsfiddle so we can help.

Comment: The side information (on google chrome) does not really help me further. I have running the scripts on different browsers: google chrome, firefox, msie, safari. It does not work on any browser. I have also tried it on another PC with 2 different browsers, but even there it does not work.